# Crossover and Mutation in Genetic Algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, genetic-algorithms

I am studying how GA works.  It is known that GA obtains the optimal solution by iteration through the the process of reproduction, crossover, and mutation.

When crossover and mutation, the probability numbers ($P_c$ and $P_m$) have to be specified.

My question is:

At each iteration, how does GA know when to crossover or mutation if we specify $P_c$ = 0.8 and $P_m$ = 0.7?

Could you give me suggestions or reference ?

Answer (score 1):

The probabilities for crossover and mutation doesn't need to be complementary. Usually the crossover is performed first (crossing two individuals with probability $P_c$) and then the mutation is applied to the resulting individuals (with probability $P_m$).

So, in your example, $80\%$ crossovers are performed and then $70\%$ of the resulting offsprings are mutated.

Comment: Thank you for your help. But how does the Pc and Pm work ? Let say if you have 10 individuals in the population. If I specify Pc 80%, it means that 8 individuals will be selected to perform crossover.  Am I understand correctly ?  What about Pm ?

Comment: Usually the crossover operation uses 2 individuals. So, if you have 20 individuals, you choose 10 pairs to cross, and with a probability of 80%, on average you're going to cross only  8 pairs.
In the case of the mutation, with a probability of 70%, if you have 20 offsprings obtained by the crossover, then you mutate on average 14 of them.